# Local storage doesn't get updated

Tags: javascript, local-storage

In the following code, after using the `deleteNote()` function, the local storage returns empty array instead of the `filteredNotes`:

```js
const mockStorage = {
    items: new Map(),
    getItem(key) {
        return this.items.get(key) ?? null;
    },
    setItem(key, value) {
        this.items.set(key, String(value));
    },
};
const notes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "first note",
        body: "some dummy first note",
        updated: "2021-10-31T15:02:00.411Z",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "second note",
        body: "some dummy second text",
        updated: "2021-10-31T15:03:23.556Z",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "third note",
        body: "this is the third note",
        updated: "2021-11-01T10:47:26.889Z",
    },
];

class NoteApi {
    static getAllNotes() {
        const savedNotes = JSON.parse(mockStorage.getItem("note-app")) || [];
        return savedNotes.sort((a, b) => {
            return new Date(a.updated) < new Date(b.updated) ? 1 : -1;
        });
    }
    static saveNote(note) {
        //1. existed note 2. isn't exist`your text`ed
        const notes = NoteApi.getAllNotes();
        const existedNote = notes.find((n) => n.id == note.id);
        if (existedNote) {
            existedNote.title = note.title;
            existedNote.body = note.body;
            existedNote.updated = new Date().toISOString();
        } else {
            note.id = new Date().getTime();
            note.updated = new Date().toISOString();
            notes.push(note);
        }
        mockStorage.setItem("note-app", JSON.stringify(notes));
    }
    static deleteNote(id) {
        const notes = NoteApi.getAllNotes();
        const filteredNotes = notes.filter((n) => n.id !== id);
        mockStorage.setItem("note-app", JSON.stringify(filteredNotes));
    }
}

NoteApi.deleteNote(2);
console.log("getAllNotes() after calling `deleteNote(2)`:");
console.log(NoteApi.getAllNotes());
```

Comment: Show us output of `const notes = NoteApi.getAllNotes();` and `filteredNotes = notes.filter((n) => n.id !== id);`. Maybe one of these returns empty list?

Comment: I've updated your question to include a Stack Snippet (with a mocked-up `localStorage`, since Stack Snippets aren't allowed to really use `localStorage`). (Side note: It's not the problem, but you were originally logging the result of calling `deleteNote`, but `deleteNote` doesn't return anything, so that will always be `undefined` (not an empty array). I've fixed that in the edit, since it wasn't the problem.)

Comment: Nothing in the code shown ever stores any notes (the `notes` you've included at the beginning are never used for anything), so there are no notes in storage in the first place, before or after calling `deleteNote`. If you actually had notes in storage, they would be returned (I've run it locally to check).

Comment: A couple of other issues: 1. `new Date().getTime()` isn't a reliable way to create an ID; for instance, if code adds two notes one right after another, they can end up with the same ID. 2. Your `sort` callback is incorrect. It always returns `1` or `-1`, but it needs to return `0` when the two items are the same. Just use `return new Date(b.updated) - new Date(a.updated);` (or `return b.updated.localeCompare(a.updated);` since the strings returned by `toISOString` can be compared lexicographically).